# Linked list - new Node pointer vs. new Node variable

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am creating a linked list for practice and I came to a problem.

I've created 2 similar codes and in the first one I create certain `structure called Node` as a `variable` and in the second code I create a `structure called Node` as a `pointer`.

In my opinion it should work the same way but it doesn't. I will post code and look at the function called `addNode()`.

Also I have a next question: Why do I have to pass pointers like this: `addNode( Node *& head, Node *& tail )` to make it work properly instead of passing them as `addNode( Node * head, Node * tail )`.

First code ( bad ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int    val;
    Node * prev;
    Node * next;

    Node( int val ) : val( val ) { }
};


void printList( Node * ptr ){
    while( ptr != NULL ){
        cout << ptr -> val << " ";
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }   
    cout << endl;
}

void addNode( int val, Node *& head, Node *& tail ){
    Node tmp( val );
    if( head == NULL ){
        head            = &tmp;
        tail            = &tmp;
        tmp . prev      = NULL;
        tmp . next      = NULL;
    }
    else{
        tail -> next    = &tmp;
        tmp . prev      = tail;
        tmp . next      = NULL;
        tail            = &tmp;
    }
}

int main(){

    Node * head         = NULL;
    Node * tail         = NULL;

    addNode( 3, head, tail );
    addNode( 8, head, tail );
    addNode( 2, head, tail );
    addNode( 4, head, tail );
    addNode( 15, head, tail );
    addNode( 11, head, tail );

    /*Node b( 5 );

    cout << b . val << endl;
    */
    printList( head );
    return 0;
}
```

Second code ( good ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int      val;
    Node * prev;
    Node * next;

    Node( int val ) : val( val ) { }
};


void printList( Node * ptr ){
    while( ptr != NULL ){
        cout << ptr -> val << " ";
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }   
    cout << endl;
}

void addNode( int val, Node *& head, Node *& tail ){
    Node * tmp = new Node( val );
    if( head == NULL ){
        head            = tmp;
        tail            = tmp;
        tmp -> prev     = NULL;
        tmp -> next     = NULL;
    }
    else{
        tail -> next    = tmp;
        tmp -> prev     = tail;
        tmp -> next     = NULL;
        tail            = tmp;
    }
}

int main(){

    Node * head         = NULL;
    Node * tail         = NULL;

    addNode( 3, head, tail );
    addNode( 8, head, tail );
    addNode( 2, head, tail );
    addNode( 4, head, tail );
    addNode( 15, head, tail );
    addNode( 11, head, tail );

    /*Node b( 5 );

    cout << b . val << endl;
    */
    printList( head );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `Node tmp`, then `tmp` is destroyed after you exit the scope in which it was defined.

On the other hand, doing `Node *tmp = new Node` allocates memory for a `Node` on the heap and gives you a pointer `tmp` to it. The `Node` is only destroyed if and when you call `delete` on it.

Coming to the second part of your question, you would want to pass a pointer by reference if you have a need to modify the pointer rather than the object that the pointer is pointing to.

If you do `head = tmp, tail = tmp` without passing `head` and `tail` by reference, then `head` and `tail` will only retain this value until the scope of this function. This change will not reflect outside of `addNode()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helped me. Your last sentence was about the fault of the program. But please, look at the last paragraph of my topic and you will see that I didn't ask if the fault is in passing pointers or in what you just explained. Question about the pointers is the next question, not related to the things that you explained.

Comment: Okay, I've added that part now.

Answer (score 1):

In order to modify `head` and `tail`using function, they must be passed by *reference* i.e second code snippet.
In first snippet, they were passed by *value*, any modification has done inside function `addNode()` will be vanished after the function out of scope.

---

**case 1**: pass by value

```
addNode(head);   // call
```

function body:

```
void addNode(Node *headCopy) {   // Node *headCopy = head,   copy is created
    headCopy = &someThing;    // the copy of head point to something else
                              // not the actual 'head' that changes its pointee
}
```

---

**case 2**: pass by reference

```
addNode(&head);
```

function body:

```
void addNode(Node *&headReference) {    // reference to 'head'
    headReference = &someThing;  // the actual 'head' changes its pointee
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since copy operation for raw-pointers is cheap there's no reason to pass it by reference.

```
void addNode( int val, Node *& head, Node *& tail ){
Node tmp( val ); // tmp - local variable
if( head == NULL ){
    head            = &tmp; // address of local variable
    tail            = &tmp; // above
    tmp . prev      = NULL;
    tmp . next      = NULL;
}
else{
    tail -> next    = &tmp; // above
    tmp . prev      = tail;
    tmp . next      = NULL;
    tail            = &tmp; // above
}
} // local variable tmp get destructed, tail head contain address of unexisting object
```

it's double-linked list, and change name of Node member val or parameter val in Node constructor, add head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), else it won't be NULL